# No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'FilterDescriptor'?

Tags: .net, model-view-controller, migration

I can't using Add-Migration. It's error
No suitable constructor was found for entity type 'FilterDescriptor'. The following constructors had parameters that could not be bound to properties of the entity type: cannot bind 'filter', 'filterScope' in 'FilterDescriptor(IFilterMetadata filter, int filterScope)'.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8C8bp.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please read [ask] and provide [mre].